What gas-law-related experiment (or experiments) might this description refer to?
Somebody on Hacker News described an experiment they performed as a teenager:

Back in high school, I built (with some parental assistance) an
apparatus to measure how quickly the pressure would drop (in a
pressurized cylinder) when a very small hole allowed air to leak out.
Turns out, not only can you measure temperature that way, but can
extrapolate the graph out to find absolute zero (IIRC my result was
out by about 20 kelvin, which I think is pretty damn good for a
high-school-garage project). (HN link)

Can somebody identify this experiment and apparatus? Is it a common demonstration? The description doesn't seem to correspond to any of the demonstrations here: https://spark.iop.org/collections/gas-laws-and-absolute-zero

Sounds related to choked flow: “the mass flow rate is independent of the downstream pressure, and depends only on the temperature and pressure and hence the density of the gas on the upstream side of the restriction.”
